# Unable to run *.sh files by directly double clicking the file in 13.04

Tags: command-line, 13.04, .sh

Facing this issue after upgrading to Raring Ringtail.
Before I could run .sh files by directly double clicking the file.
But now it goes directly for editing instead of opening up a pop window which will allow me either to Run in Terminal or Edit.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do a right click and go to `Properties`=>`Permissions`. Set `Allow executing file as program`. If you now double click it should run.

Comment: that I did but still not working I think I need to go back to 12.10 there wasn’t a problem